# Гиперссылка к выпадающему списку

Tags: html

```html
<select name="range" size="1" class="ib280ss" onchange="refreshAll();">
  <option value="1" selected="">За вчера и сегодня</option>
  <option value="7">За последние 7 дней</option>
  <option value="14">За последние 14 дней</option>
  <option value="30">За последние 30 дней</option>
  <option value="100">Все</option>
</select>
```

Вот код выпадающего списка. Не могу прикрутить к слову "Все" гиперссылку. Как этого достичь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```html
<select name="range" onchange="if (this.value==100) document.location = 'http://your_url';/*refreshAll();*/" size="1" class="ib280ss">
  <option value="1" selected="">За вчера и сегодня</option>
  <option value="7">За последние 7 дней</option>
  <option value="14">За последние 14 дней</option>
  <option value="30">За последние 30 дней</option>
  <option value="100">Все</option>
</select>
```

Лучше конечно, если вы код из `onchange` переместите в функцию `refreshAll`.